# how recover lost data of coordinates from contourplot of mention data?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, graphics, functions, fitting

I have made `Contour Plot` for a lot of data, like this

```
ListContourPlot[ data, DataRange -> {{yMin, yMax}, {xMin, xMax}}, 
                 AxesLabel -> {"y", "x"}, PlotRange -> All, 
                 PlotLegends -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow"]
```

[image]

but now I lost my data (the coordinates).
How I can recover those in such way that I can plot them by:

```
ListContourPlot[recovereddata]
```

or preferably

```
ListContourPlot[ recovereddata, DataRange -> {{yMin, yMax}, {xMin, xMax}},
                 AxesLabel -> {"y", "x"}, PlotRange -> All, 
                 PlotLegends -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow"]
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you have the generated *Mathematica* contour plots in a Notebook still?

Comment: Yes only plots, but I have not the list of coordinates.

Comment: FullForm[plot] will reveal the data  (paste in the graphic if thats all you have).

Comment: Sorry, after posting that I took a look and I think the ListContourPlot object *does not* contain the original data - you may be SOL.

Comment: @george2079 I think the question is how to approximate the data from back calculation, rather than merely extracting it.  It expect that it will be complicated.  The data does not have to be perfect, only close enough to produce a similar plot.  Mushegh, can you confirm my understanding?

Comment: If the end goal is to modify the figure (labels, colors, etc), some of that might be doable directly (without generating approximate data). Best clarify what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Yes I confirm it Mr.Wizard.

Comment: Now I want to plot the difference of already generated two plots, which data I lost. I know the Show function which can modify the labels, colors and so on.

Comment: I generated a lot of graphs by ListContourPlot[data], where the datas are the list of numbers which calculation are very long. Now I need to plot their difference, but then maybe I will need to do other things, therefor I wanted to keep the list of the coordinated

Comment: Please help me, in other case, I will loos a few weeks on recalculations. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
plot = ListContourPlot[ Flatten[ Table[{x, y, Sin[Pi x] Cos[2 Pi y]} ,
                   {x, -1,  1, .1}, {y, -1, 1, .1}], 1]]
data = List @@ (First@Cases[plot, _GraphicsComplex]);
clines = ((Rest@#) & /@ Cases[data[[2]], {_Directive, ___}, Infinity])
                    /.  i_Integer :> data[[1, i]];
Graphics[  clines ]
cvals = Table[ i, {i, .8, -.8, -.2}]; (*table of contour line values*)
pointsets = 
  Flatten[MapIndexed[
       Append[#1, cvals[[#2[[1]]]]] &, (Flatten[# /. Line -> List, 2]) & /@
 clines , {2}], 1];
ListContourPlot[pointsets]
```

To be clear, this is *not* recovering the actual input data, it works by pulling the points used to construct the contour lines.

If you only have the graphic you can do    `plot = (*paste graphic*) shift-enter`

The contour values are there in "Tooltips", but I cant figure how to extract that info so I just set manually..

Comment: Thank you very much, but it doesn't work for my case, I think it is because my contours are more complicated (see picture above)

Comment: "doesnt work" isn't much to go on..  Do you get a plot at all?  One issue i see with your data is not that its *complicated* but that you have large boundary region with no contour lines. You might need to manually add some edge points to get it to look right.

Answer (score 1):

A similar approach to george2079, extracting the coordinates of the contour lines and getting the z values from the tooltips:

```
lcp = ListContourPlot[Array[Norm[{##}] &, {20, 20}, -5]]
```

[image]

```
data = Reap[Cases[Normal@DeleteCases[lcp, _Polygon, -1],
     Tooltip[{_, lines__}, z_] :>
      ({lines} /. {x_Real, y_Real} :> Sow[{x, y, z}]), -1]][[2, 1]];
```

This is the data, you can see how it corresponds to the contour lines:

```
ListPointPlot3D[data]
```

[image]

Recreating the contour plot:

```
ListContourPlot[data]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Simon Woods, it is plotting something but it is not the initial picture, I think it is because my contour plots are more complicated (see picture above, I have added it)

Comment: @Mushegh, perhaps you will need to interpolate the extracted data points, or do a fit. If you can provide a link to the original plot I would be happy to have another go.

Comment: Sorry, where and how I can upload my plot? I am registered here recently