# Recovering data from an existing plot

Tags: plotting

I have some plots in an old Mathematica notebook that I'd like to re-create in Matplotlib (for stylistic consistency with the rest of the plots in my thesis).

Unfortunately, I've lost the data that I used to generate these plots.  Since the plots are still intact, is it possible to extract the coordinates of the data points from them?  I know that I can use "Get Coordinates" from the context menu on the plot, but this is tedious and imprecise!

They were generated in version 8 or 9, I think.  This is the code that I used to generate the plots:

```
MoneyPlot[dataSets_, Vs_, fs_] := 
  Show @@ {ListLogLogPlot[dataSets[[1, 1]], 
      PlotStyle -> dataSets[[1, 2]],
      Joined -> True
      (* Some more options *)
      ]}~Join~
    Table[ListLogLogPlot[data[[1]], PlotStyle -> data[[2]], 
      Joined -> True], {data, dataSets[[2 ;;]]}];
```

[image: Example plot]

Comment: Could you post an example plot?

Comment: Were these plots made in MMA V6 or later? @DavidG.Stork's question is important, because we need to know what types of plots (`Plot`, `ContourPlot`, `DensityPlot`, etc.) these are, how many traces are shown on each plot, etc. So please post an example!

Comment: related http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38257/2079

Comment: [Related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19859/plot-extract-data-to-a-file), if not a duplicate.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As explained by `anderstood`, if you don't have the plots named, you need to copy and paste the figure into an input cell and type, say, `fig =` in front of the figure, then evaluate.

Suppose you generated a `MoneyPlot` named `fig`. Then, you can extract the data making up those curves using

```
data = Cases[fig // Normal, Line[a_] :> a, Infinity]
```

In order to test and see if it has extracted correctly, do

```
ListPlot[#] & /@ data
```

and you should see a `List` of `Plot`s, one for each of the curves above.

For the purposes of illustration,

```
fig = Plot[{x^2, x^3, x^4}, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic]
data = Cases[fig // Normal, Line[a_] :> a, Infinity];
ListPlot[#] & /@ %
```

results in

[image]

Since you have a `LogLogPlot`, if you want the actual values, rather than the values of the exponents, you just need to wrap `data` with `Exp`:

```
originalValues = Exp[data];
```

---

One more thing: this method requires that the points in your figure be `Joined`, as you've shown. If that is *not* the case, then you have to extract the `Point`s instead. For instance,

```
fig = ListLogLogPlot[Table[{x, #}, {x, 0.01, 1, 0.01}] & /@ {x, x^2, x^3}, Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic]
data = Cases[fig // Normal, Point[a_] :> a, Infinity];
ListPlot[#] & /@ data
ListPlot[Exp[data]]
```

results in

[image]

Comment: I am not sure if he can name the figure `fig` as, if I understand correctly, he cannot run `MoneyPlot` since he lost the data. I guess he just has the image saved in a *.nb. The only solution I see is to copy and paste.

Comment: @anderstood. Agreed. I will edit as necessary.

Comment: Thanks both – this has saved me!

Comment: @Ruslan . I think those points were addressed in the second part of my post?

Comment: Oh indeed, hadn't read up to there :)

Answer (score 7):

- First step for illustration purpose : generate an image

`MoneyPlot[{{{1, 2, 6}, {6, 3, 3}}}, 0, 0]`

[image: enter code here]

- Copy the plot and paste it instead of `PASTE`:

  `fig=PASTE;`
- Get the points (in log-log) and take the exponential:

  `Map[Exp, fig[[1, 2, 3, 4, 1]]]`

> Output: `{{1., 1.}, {2., 2.}, {3., 6.}}`

You might have to adjust the indexes in `fig`.