# Extract data from plots created inside the module environment

Tags: plotting, scoping

I need to extract the data from plots created inside the module environment to re draw my plots in a better plotter that Mathematica.

I have a code that includes several matrix multiplications, and works with data that i introduce every time i need to run the function created in the module environment. So, i already have this graphs thanks to the Print option, but i can't extract the coordinates from this plots inside that environment with the answers given in the forums.

Code:

```
grafi[inf_,sup_,tem_] := Module[{x, m1, m2, matri, elem22, co},
  m1[x_] = ( {{x, 100},{10, tem}} );
  m2[x_] = ( {{200, 1},{tem, x}} );
  matri[x_] = m2[x].m1[x].m2[x];

  elem22[x_] := matri[x][[2, 2]] ;
  co[x_] := 1/Abs[elem22[x]]^2;

  Print[Plot[co[x], {x, inf, sup}]]

  ]
```

If later I call the function grafi like this:

```
grafi[10,10000,50]
```

I obtain the plot i want. But i can't extract the data from here. Help! Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a **minimal** example to work with and describe what exactly do you need at the end. What about [94481](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/94481/5478)?

Comment: How about not just printing them, but placing them explicitly in the output? e.g. `Module[{vars}, calculations; Print[plots]; {originaloutput, plot1, plot2, plot3}]`? Then manipulate the output as you please.

Comment: Hey @LLlAMnYP, i think i had that idea in the past but i couldn't get the data for some reason. Would you be more specific so i can try it again in this way? Thanks.

Comment: Use `.` instead of `*` to multiply matrices; see [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/575). Also, remove the `Print[]` as it does not make the plot easily usable by other functions. Thus: `grafi[inf_, sup_, opts___] := Plot[1/Abs[({{200, 1}, {x, x}}.{{x, 100}, {10, 50}}.{{200, 1}, {x, x}})[[2, 2]]]^2 // Evaluate, {x, inf, sup}, opts]; grafi[10, 1*^4]`

Comment: "I can't extract the coordinates from this plot" - again, the `Print[]` is the problem there; remove it so that you can do something like `Cases[plot, Line[l_] :> l, ∞]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your function a bit since `Print` is not needed:

```
grafi[inf_, sup_, tem_] := 
 Module[{x, m1, m2, matri, elem22, co}, 
  m1[x_] = ({{x, 100}, {10, tem}});
  m2[x_] = ({{200, 1}, {tem, x}});
  matri[x_] = m2[x].m1[x].m2[x];
  elem22[x_] := matri[x][[2, 2]];
  co[x_] := 1/Abs[elem22[x]]^2;
  Plot[co[x], {x, inf, sup}]]
```

and then this

```
pl = grafi[10, 10000, 50]
```

gives you a plot

[image]

Now the list of points to be plotted have the tree coordinates `{1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1}`. Thus, this

```
lst = pl[[1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1]]
```

gives you the desired list of points. Let us check it:

```
PlotList[lst]
```

[image]

Done, have fun!